# How does Map Reduce ensure all the data of a single xml record split across different Files go to the same mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a huge set of XML records split across different files. Now If a record starts in File 1 but does not end there. Instead it is continued in some other file say File10. How will the Map Reduce framework identify that the remaining pat of the record so that it is processed by the same mapper?

Comment: try a custom recordreader/inputFormat, which ensures splits.

Comment: by default it will not be processed by the same mapper. Different files => different mappers.